# Загрузка определенной страницы через Webkit в приложении

Tags: swift, xcode, webkit

Только начал учить Swift/Xcode, пробую кнопкой открыть в приложении нужную страницу webkitом. Сам Xcode спокойно компилирует приложение, запускается и работает до нажатия. Дальше дебаг ругается:

`Exception  NSException *   "-[UIView openpagef:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f92fa808a60"   0x000060000092e0a0`

Почитал по ошибке что он вроде не понимает куда эта кнопка нажимает, и следовательно, выбрасывает.

В сториборде выглядит это дело вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно сам код:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class Wkfillials: WKWebView {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBAction func openpagef( sender: Any) {
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://rechitsamuseum.online/главная/филиалы/")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

Я уверен что мой косяк на 100% связан с незнанием кода и/или синтаксиса, спасибо всем ответившим заранее.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит о том, что программа пытается вызвать несуществующую функцию (селектор). Несуществующую, потому что судя по коду webView не создан. Вам нужно или явно создать webView или через аутлет. Попробуйте вот так например:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func openpagef(_ sender: Any) {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://apple.com") {
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    
}
```

Comment: Заменил код - не сработало. Ругается на ту же ошибку. Это может быть связано с тем, что кнопкой из одного View Controller Scene я пытаюсь открыть другой View Controller Scene и одновременно загрузить ссылку через Webview?

Comment: Атлет подключили во ViewController?

Comment: Да, он подключён. На всякий случай удалил кнопку и webview, добавил заново. Появилось вот что:
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value.

Дебаг показывает:
webView = (WKWebView?) nil
url = (URL) <unavailable; try printing with "vo" or "po">

Comment: Покажите итоговый код

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBAction func openpagef(_ sender: Any) {
            if let url = URL(string: "https://apple.com") { webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
      }
   }
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    
}
```

Итоговый код, атлет подключен, но появилось вот что: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value. Дебаг показывает: webView = (WKWebView?) nil url = (URL) <unavailable; try printing with "vo" or "po">